# IOS UIAlertView not showing up

Tags: ios, uialertview, alert

I want to pop up a simple message window when a user touches the button, in an IPhone app. I used UIAlertView class, in the implementation code like this:

```
-(IBAction)sendMessage:(UIButton *)sender

{
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"test message"
                                                         message:@"test"
                                                        delegate:nil
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];


    [alert show];
}
```

I also linked sendMessage method action to touch up inside.

Shows nothing.

Have any ideas? I'm new to iOS programming.
Thanks for helping.

Comment: Use a breakpoint to make sure the `[alert show]` gets called

Comment: Yes, starting with general debugging, like breakpoints, is a good start. But this question needs more information in order to be properly answered. Shots of the IB connections for starters.

Comment: If `sendMessage` is called and the app isn't crashing, then `[alert show];` is almost definitely called.  My guess would be that `sendMessage` isn't actually called.

Comment: Put NSLog at first line on this method. Do you see anything in console?

Answer (score 1):

You need to link up the button in your storyboard/xib file to the function or call or set it up in code

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(sendMessage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest two things, give it a try:

1) Set `delegate` to `self`.

2) Try making the IBAction argument type to `id`. Then remove and reconnect from Interface builder.

Something like this:

```
-(IBAction)sendMessage:(id)sender

{
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"test message"
                                                         message:@"test"
                                                        delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];


    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: Sorry my mistake, i linked the wrong button touch action, now fixed it and works fine. hope you don't mind, thank you..

Answer (score 1):

```
  NSString* messageString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"\"%@ \"does not apppear to be valid email address.Do You Want sent Anyway?", email];

            UIAlertView *alertView =[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Invalid adress" message:messageString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
            [alertView show];
```